# Static method throws error when returning object / string?

Tags: php, exception, laravel, return-value, static-methods

In Laravel I have created a Utils file with some static methods to do various things. One of them is to grab data from Bandcamp's api. The function is called from a subview called releases.small. I'm not sure if blade inheritance is involved here or not but here is the way the views are arranged.

**templates.default** -> **artists.view** (@extends(templates.default)) -> **releases.discography** (included in artists.view) -> **releases.small** (included in releases.discography)

In 'releases.small' I have the following code:

```
$data = Utils::apiAlbumData($release->bandcamp['url']);
```

Below is the code for `Utils::apiAlbumData($url)` and  `Utils::albumIdFromAlbumUrl($url)`. There are commented out echo statements there which I put in just to verify that the functions were working. `albumIdFromAlbumUrl()` returns a valid id number which is used in the `file_get_contents`. After using `json_decode` I can access $data attributes such as `$data->small_art_url` and when I `print_r($data)` it looks as it should.

```
public static function apiAlbumData($url) {

    $aid = Utils::albumIdFromAlbumUrl($url);
    // echo $aid; // this fine, echoes the expected number

    $json = file_get_contents("http://api.bandcamp.com/api/album/2/info?key=vatnajokull&album_id=" . $aid . "&debug");
    $data = json_decode($json);
    return $data;
    //return "some text";

    /*
    echo $data->small_art_url . "<br />";  // fine
    echo $data->album_id . "<br />";  // fine
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($data);  // fine
    //echo "</pre>";
    die;
    */

}

public static function albumIdFromAlbumUrl($url) {

    $json = file_get_contents ("http://api.bandcamp.com/api/url/1/info?key=vatnajokull&url=" . urlencode($url));
    $data = json_decode ($json);
    return $data->album_id;

}
```

if I try to return $data from the class laravel instead of just printing it to screen the following exception is thrown:

**ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)** 
*Undefined property: stdClass::$album_id (View: /home/shane478/beta/dv/app/views/releases/small.blade.php) (View: /home/shane478/beta/dv/app/views/releases/small.blade.php) (View: /home/shane478/beta/dv/app/views/releases/small.blade.php)*

The very same error occurs if i try to return "some text" instead of $data. Then it shows me Utils::albumIdFromAlbumUrl($url) which has the line *return $data->album_id*; but I know that that function is working ok because I echoed it's return value in apiAlbumData($url). 'album_id' appears in none of the other view files.

What am I doing wrong?!

**EDIT - just adding in view files and controller function in response to comment below. Too much info probably...**
I've also cut out one of the views from above, the now look like this:

**templates.default** -> **artists.view** (@extends(templates.default)) -> **releases.discography** (included in artists.view)

here is `releases/discography.blade.php` (containing the problem static method commented out)

```
{{-- */ $i=1; /* --}}

<div data-equalizer>

  @foreach($artist->releases as $release)


  <div class="large-{{$discsize}} columns panel release-small" data-equalizer-watch>

    @if(Str::startsWith($release->image, 'http'))
    <img src="{{ $release->image }}" />
    @elseif(is_numeric ($release->image))
    <img   src="url-to-file-here" />
    @else
    <img src="http://example.com/{{ $release->image }}" />
    @endif

    <h4>{{ $release->title }}</h4>

    @foreach ($release->issues as $issue)
      {{ $issue->type }}: {{ date('Y', strtotime($issue->date)) }}<br />
      @foreach($issue->items as $item)
      {{ $item->cat_num }} | {{ $item->format->format }}
      @endforeach

      <?php // $data =  Utils::apiAlbumData($release->bandcamp['url']); ?>

    @endforeach

   </div>   

  {{-- */ $i++; /* --}}
  @if ( ($i - $rowsize == 1) && ($i < count($artist->releases)) )   
  {{-- */ $i=1; /* --}}
</div>
<div  data-equalizer>
@endif

@endforeach

</div>
```

here is `releases/view.blade.php`:

```
@extends('templates.default')

@section('pagetitle')
{{ $artist->name }} : 
@stop

@section('content')

<div class="large-12">
  <h2>{{ Utils::sortOrder($artist->name) }}</h2>
  {{ nl2br($artist->about) }}
</div>

@include('releases.discography')

@stop
```

Here is the controller method responsible

```
public function view($slug) {

    $artist = Artist::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    list ($discSize, $discsPerRow) = Utils::calculateRowItems(count ($artist->releases));

    return View::make('artists.view')->withArtist($artist)->withDiscsize($discSize)->withRowsize($discsPerRow);

}
```

Comment: YOu error is coming from a blade template -- but you're not showing how you're handing data off to that template.  This makes me wonder if the problem isn't in your static call, but something else around view creation.

Answer (score 0):

you should be sure that file_get_contents returns a json string with object inside and has no errors. So you should check:

```
$data = json_decode ($json);
if (is_object($data) && $data->error != true) {
    return $data->album_id;
}
return false;
```

Comment: I tried that but with no luck. I think the json is ok as I can print_r it and access $data->album_id and $data->whatever_else inside the static function. The result of print_r starts off **stdClass Object ( [band_id] => 2759811402** - that's as it should be i think?.